# Simple assignment of characters from one string to other is not working

Tags: c++

I am trying to assign characters from one string to other using function but I am getting  error.

> "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
>     what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void split (std::string line)
{
    std::string::size_type leng=0;
    leng=line.length();
    std::string k;

    for (long unsigned int i=0;i<leng; i++)
    {
        k.at(i)=line.at(i);
    }

    std::cout<<k;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line = "";
    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(std::cin, line);
    split(line);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you initialize `k` it is an emtpy string. So `k.at(i)` will be out of of bounds as the error message says.

There are plenty of ways to copy a string, you could use a constructor like `std::string k(line);` or `k.assign(line)` or you could use [resize()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) to resize `k` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown because any new string that is created whitout initial content, have 0 len.
Accessing characters via `at()` expect that index have a character, but the `k` have no no value *even at 0*.

You can resize the string first, and then use `at()`

```cpp
std::string k;
k.resize(leng);
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void split (std::string line)
{
    std::string::size_type leng = line.length();
    std::string k;

    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < leng; i++)
    {
        k.push_back(line.at(i));  // This is the only real change
    }

    std::cout << k;
}


int main()
{
    std::string line = "";
    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(std::cin, line);
    split(line);
}
```

When `k` is declared, it is empty. It's size is therefore 0. You are using the `.at()` function, which accesses a specific element (character) and throws an exception when you go out of bounds. You immediately go out of bounds because `k` is empty.

Now, your function doesn't split (yet, or you left that part out), but `.push_back()` seems like it will fit what you're trying to do best. It will add the characters to the end of the string, and grow the string as needed; you won't have to worry about manually managing its size.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access an element of an empty string, please use this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void split (const std::string& line) // pass parameter by reference to avoid copy
{
    std::string::size_type leng = line.length();
    std::string k;
    k.resize(leng); // use resize to create space for the new characters

    for (long unsigned int i = 0; i < leng; i++)
    {
        k.at(i)=line.at(i);
    }

    std::cout << k;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line = "";
    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    getline(std::cin, line);
    split(line);
}
```